How to start Simgrid parallel mode？
When I ran several actors in a host with multi-cores, I found that it takes a lot of time, because the simulation almost ran on a physical core. So I want to run the code in parallel.
I wrote a line of code in the main function：
simgrid::s4u::Engine::set_config("contexts/nthreads:2");

but an error was encountered:
Segmentation fault.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

And then I added:
simgrid::s4u::Engine::set_config("host/model:ptask_L07");

However I still met "Segmentation fault"(e.run()). I don't know if it's a missing configuration item or a logical error.
UPD: My backtrace is:
#0  0x00007ffff76c6b05 in std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7b148b9 in simgrid::kernel::activity::ExecImpl::post() ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsimgrid.so.3.30
#2  0x00007ffff7b73c36 in simgrid::kernel::EngineImpl::wake_all_waiting_actors() const ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsimgrid.so.3.30
#3  0x00007ffff7b7b325 in simgrid::kernel::EngineImpl::run(double) ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsimgrid.so.3.30
#4  0x000055555555b834 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdf58)
    at /home/zinnia/project/SimgridTest/src/SimgridTest.cpp:115


Hello, it would be nice if you could provide a backtrace of the segfault, either using gdb (run your code in gdb and then type bt once the segfault occurs) or using valgrind (just run your code in valgrind). It's always possible that your segfault is not related to the parallel mode, and we need the backtrace to check that it is.

Done.@Martin Quinson

It works without any set_config() calls? And valgrind reports no error then? I would be surprised if this segfault comes from simgrid itself. It looks like an error in the user code instead, but I may be wrong.
Please confirm that it works with no error in valgrind when you remove all set_config() calls.

The classical way of enabling the parallel mode is to pass --cfg=contexts/nthreads:2 on the command line instead. This option is so intrusive that it may not play well with the set_config function.
In addition, you should check on this paper to see how our parallel mode works. You will see that it may or may not speed up your simulations, depending on where the bottleneck lays. In short, it will only speed things up if you're playing nice on the simulation kernel while your code does a lot of computation in the userland (few interactions with the simulator, many big computations that are not related with SimGrid). In this case, an even better solution is to remove your big computations from your code (see for example the idea of execution sampling in MPI-based simulation). Not having any big computations is always faster than running these big computations in parallel.
If the bottleneck is in the simulator itself, then the parallel mode will not help. Please give more context in another question on need.
